# Changing login name to svn repository from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, authentication

Using Eclipse I added a SVN repository & imported a project using another person's login and automatically checked remember login.  One can't always wait for IT people.  Now I have my very own name and would like to switch logins.  Can this be done without uninstalling the world?  I'm using WIndow 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to:

1. Open SVN repository view
2. Right click on the repository of the project you checked out
3. Select Location Properties...
4. Change use credential

Otherwise, the other solution is to:

1. Right click on your project
2. Team --> Disconnect --> Also delete SVN Metadata
3. Team --> Share Project --> And you the right location with your credential

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of how Eclipse's SVN implementation works, but for for most SVN clients you can force Subversion to forget its previous credentials by trashing the directory `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth`